# Pushing user entered data into JSON inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am making a completely offline HTML5 App.

In one part of the app, I am required to

1. fetch a JSON data stored in localStorage, then
2. Push a new row to it.
3. Save the data back.

Anyhow, in the step 2, I have to push some javaScript variables (which come from an HTML form), I am not able to do that.

This is what I have tried:

```
var goalsStr = localStorage.getItem("goals");
var goalsObj = JSON.parse(goalsStr);
data =
    '{"goal":"' + goal + '","duedate":"' + date2 + '","noofdays":"' + diff + '","active:"' + active + '"}';
goalsObj.goals.push(data);
localStorage.setItem("goals",
JSON.stringify(goalsObj));
```

The problem here is tht all the data is getting stored with a  - /"   istead of having just -  "

What's wrong? What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: you are pushing a string into array, not an object. Assume you want `goalsObj.goals` to be an array of objects?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes goalsObj.goals is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `data` to be an object literal which would make `goalObj.goals` an array of objects

```
var data = {
    "goal": goal,
    "duedate": date2,
    "noofdays": diff,
    "active": active
};
```

Comment: I left the quotes on object keys...but those aren't even needed when creating object literal unless have special characters in keys